# Implementation Of instanceOf function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hello people of Stackoverflow!  I have been going through the Mozilla Developer Network's JavaScript Guide and came across this function on the [Details of the object model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model) page:

The function is to check if an object is an instance of an object constructor:

```
function instanceOf(object, constructor) {
   while (object != null) {
      if (object == constructor.prototype)
         return true;
      if (typeof object == 'xml') {
        return constructor.prototype == XML.prototype;
      }
      object = object.__proto__;
   }
   return false;
}
```

My question is that, from the same page it says that is `chris` is an object of type `Engineer` then the following code returns true:

```
chris.__proto__ == Engineer.prototype;
```

However, in the above `instanceOf` function, it uses the following comparison expression to check if an object is an instance of a constructor function:

```
object == constructor.prototype
```

Should the expression not be:

```
object.__proto__ == constructor.prototype
```

Or am I missing a point here?  Thank you all for your help and time in advance!

Comment: aha, thanks for that! I think I spent too much time straight on coding.  Break time :P

Comment: You should probably accept the correct answer instead of just commenting.

Comment: @millimoose the answer was previously a comment itself.  How do you think I'd accept that? Now I can and did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the statement `object = object.__proto__;` at the bottom of the `while` loop... This traverses the prototype-chain. The `object` variable contains the current object from that chain for each step of the traversal.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a little late but the following is a snippet that should behave exactly like isInstanceOf

```
Object.prototype.instanceOf = function (type) {
    let proto = this.__proto__;
    while (proto) {
        if (proto.constructor && proto.constructor === type)
            return true;
        if (proto.__proto__)
            proto = proto.__proto__;
        else
            break;
    }
    return false;
};

console.log(Number(12).instanceOf(Number));  //true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function C() {}
function D() {}

var o = new C();

// true, because: Object.getPrototypeOf(o) === C.prototype
o instanceof C;
```

instanceOf will check the prototype for left side object with right side object.