# javascript Function.prototype issue

Tags: javascript, function, prototype, instanceof

I started learning JavaScript and have below question:

```js
var f = function foo() {}
Console.log(f.__proto__ === Function.prototype) //true 
Console.log(f.__proto__ instance of Function) //false
```

Why 3rd statement using instanceof returns false. My understanding is RHS of instance consults prototype of passed class and then match it in object or its proto. Please let me know what I am missing here?
referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122955/implementation-of-instanceof-function-in-javascript) for implementation of instance-of.

Comment: You have syntax errors: `instanceof` is one word, and `console` must be lowercase.

Comment: you can refer [`JavaScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: related, if not duplicate: [Why is Object.prototype instanceof Object false?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26962278/1048572)

Comment: yes, it's typo instanceof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122955/implementation-of-instanceof-function-in-javascript) for implementation of instance-of

Well, that's simply a wrong implementation. The [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator does not match the object itself, only its prototypes, against the `.prototype` of the constructor. Your

```
x instanceof Function
```

is equivalent to

```
Function.prototype.isPrototypeOf(x)
```

which for `f.__proto__` (i.e. `Function.prototype`) does not hold - it is not the prototype of itself.

Comment: Thanks, i have no idea about isprototypeof. will read about that. IN this case f.__proto__ ->Function.prototype; instanceof finds prototype property of RHS i.e. Function.prototype and then tries to find a match. Isn't that correct? If not, is there a way to find implemented code of instanceof.

Comment: Yes, it tries to find `Function.prototype` (the LHS) in the prototype chain of the `.prototype` of `Function` (the RHS). But it is not in the chain, it is the start of the chain.

Comment: You can read about `isPrototypeOf` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf)